# Get a Query that can display of 30 days based on table data and not current date

Tags: sql, oracle

Hie I want to extract data from 3 tables and their rows as follows:
`**RentalAgreement – CustID,AgreementID(PK) and AgreementDate 
**Movie Rented  – AgreementID(PK), RentalAmount and PercentReductionApplied,MovieID(FK)
**Movie         – MovieID(PK), Name, Released`

Where i need to display the data from last 30 days based on table and not the current data. 
How can i go about achieving this?
My try:

```
SELECT TRIM(CustID),AgreementDate , RentalAmount    
             ,PercentReductionApplied , MovieID , Name , Released
FROM RentalAgreement, MovieRented, Movie
WHERE RentalAgreement.AgreementID = MovieRented.AgreementID
AND Movie.MovieID = MovieRented.MovieID
AND AgreementDate BETWEEN MAX(AgreementDate) AND MAX(AgreementDate)-30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with MAX(agreementdate). That is an aggregate function - you can only access it in the last stage of a query (in the SELECT clause), after the WHERE clause has been processed. Which means you need a different query to compute the MAX first - and use it as a subquery in your overall (outer) query.

It is also best to use modern, SQL standard join syntax. Putting both of these together:

```
SELECT TRIM(CustID),AgreementDate , RentalAmount    
             ,PercentReductionApplied , MovieID , Name , Released
FROM RentalAgreement
     join MovieRented on RentalAgreement.AgreementID = MovieRented.AgreementID
     join Movie       on Movie.MovieID               = MovieRented.MovieID
     cross join (select max(agreementdate) as max_date from rentalagreement) m
where AgreementDate BETWEEN m.max_date AND m.max_date - 30;
```

Why do you need to TRIM(custID)? That's quite unusual. Also odd that AgreementID is PRIMARY key in MovieRented. But these are not the reasons your query didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = MAX(AgreementDate) FROM RentalAgreement
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,-30,@StartDate)

SELECT TRIM(CustID),AgreementDate , RentalAmount
             ,PercentReductionApplied , MovieID , Name , Released
FROM RentalAgreement, MovieRented, Movie
WHERE RentalAgreement.AgreementID = MovieRented.AgreementID
AND Movie.MovieID = MovieRented.MovieID
AND AgreementDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate